# How to include third-party packages in my react library package?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, rollup, react-library

I have a **React library package** configured with **typescript** and **rollup**.

This package includes some components based on the company's UI-kit and we customized components of third-party packages like **mui** and we use them in our projects.

The problem is the **types** of third-party packages. When I bundle the package and publish it in our private registry, after installing the package in the project, we can't access to **extended props** of mui components.

**In other words, the imported types from the mui package, won't include in build process.**

What is wrong and what should I do for my package?

This is how I use types of mui.

```
import { ButtonProps } from '@mui/material/Button';

export interface IButtonProps extends ButtonProps {}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "assets/*": ["assets/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"]
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "dist/cjs/bundle.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/bundle.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "dist/styles"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && rollup -c && sass ./src/styles/index.scss dist/styles/index.css",
    "pre-build": "npm run lint && npm run format && npm run test",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --detectOpenHandles",
    "test:dev": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "format": "prettier src -w",
    "storybook": "sass ./src/styles/index.scss public/compiled.css && storybook dev -p 6006",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "author": "hajalizaa",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   /// my dependencies
  }
}
```

rollup.config.mjs

```
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import alias from 'rollup-plugin-alias';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import copyAssets from 'rollup-plugin-copy-assets';
import copyFiles from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve({
        preferRelative: true
      }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
      postcss({
        modules: true
      }),
      terser(),
      alias(),
      image(),
      copyAssets({
        assets: ['src/assets']
      }),
      copyFiles({
        targets: [{ src: 'src/styles', dest: 'dist' }],
        flatten: true,
        hook: 'writeBundle'
      }),
      json()
    ]
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/esm/types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.(css|less|scss)$/]
  }
];
```